# Does Multiupload Filefield Widget for Drupal provides a Form API element?

Tags: forms, files

I have a form in on of my Drupal page that uses Multiupload Filefield Widget to upload multiple images at once.

I want to alter the functionality of this Multiupload Filefield Widget from my custom module using hook_form_alter.

At first I thought It will be a `managed_file` widget. But it is not.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Did you try `hook_form_alter` to check multiupload filefield widget?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: No. How to do that?

Comment: ,how are you rendering the form in page?

Comment: For future: in `hook_form_alter` you can simply `dpr($form)` or `var_dump($form)`  and see what's what ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does, as defined in `multiupload_filefield_widget_element_info()`. The element type is `mfw_managed_file`, so you can use something like:

```
$form['multi_upload_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'mfw_managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Some file'),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
);
```